# How to convert a string into int with python library pyjq?

Tags: python

How can I use `pyjq` to convert incoming String into integer?
As of now, `pyjq` returns a string for `x` attribute, and I understand why it's doing that, but isn't there any function that I can add to the schema in order to convert it into integer?

**Code:**

```
# apply incoming data to template
def apply(template_name: str, data):
    result = pyjq.one(
        import_template(template_name),
        data
    )
```

**Incoming event data:**

```
    "dynamodb": {
        "NewImage": {
            "x": {
                "N": "3"
            },
```

**Schema template:**

```
"event": {
        "data": {
            "x": .dynamodb.NewImage.x.N,
                }
         }
```

**Output:**

```
"event": {
        "data": {
            "x": "3",
                }
         }
```

*Looking for a solution to get output like below:*

**Output:**

```
"event": {
        "data": {
            "x": 3,
                }
         }
```

Comment: Can you modify the template? You can pipe the result of `dynamodb.NewImage.x.N` to the `tonumber` filter, e.g. `jq '{event: { data: {x: .dynamodb.NewImage.x.N | tonumber}}}' tmp.json`.

Comment: You saved me @chepner :) Salute. it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jq` can convert a string to an number using the `tonumber` filter.

Change the template to:

```
"event": {
        "data": {
            "x": .dynamodb.NewImage.x.N | tonumber
                }
         }
```